# Scaling UIlabel Text using Gesture

Tags: iphone, ipad, uilabel, gesture

I am scaling `UILabel` text using UIPinchGestureRecognizer. But I am not able achieve the smooth edges or smoothness of Text.

[image]

code for scaling:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
        [pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        [holderView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];


  -(void)scale:(id)sender {

        [self bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];

        if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

            lastScale = 1.0;
            return;
        }


        CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);


        CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
        CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

        [[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

        lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
    }
```

[image]

Comment: can you please post your code how did you achieved as I am stuck with same problem ??

Comment: @Jennis I have sent the code to your mail id

Comment: Hi @Anand: can u share your code with me as I am also stuck into same problem.

Comment: @fibnochi send me your mail id

Comment: @Anand, Have you tried it for multi-line text label? does it work properly for it also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're scaling using a transformation. That takes the original rendering and scales it up or down, but doesn't change it. In other words: the "quality" doesn't change, only at what size you're displaying it. What you want instead is probably to do the following steps:

- Reset the transformation back to identity (need to do this for the next step).
- Calculate and apply new frame size, reposition view.
- Apply rotation transformation.

By changing the frame size the view is drawn again with the new size which will result in better quality than scaling up a smaller view.

I'm not sure whether changing the frame is possible during pinching (it might be messing with the recognizer), maybe you need to apply the transformation you're doing right now and do the change-frame-size-method when the gesture is done to get a high quality version after the pinch is finished (you can see a similar pattern sometimes with scroll views).

Comment: you are right changing the frame size we can achieve smooth edges but we can't detect pinch after changing frame of UILabel.

Comment: In this case you will have to scale using a transform while pinching, and once the pinch is done you scale using frame size. So while pinching it may look a little ugly, but once the user lifts his fingers it will look good.